# Code Consolidation for Processing Custom Data Structure

Tags: vba, function, data-structures, ms-project, callbyname

I have developed a VBA application in MS Project to measure the quality of a project schedule.  My app analyzes every task in a schedule and determines 35 different attributes which are then combined in various ways to compute 13 different quality scores.  The program works great and produces the correct results, but I want to consolidate the code in various functions so it is not verbose (e.g., eliminate the Select Case statements).  Details are as follows:

```vb
Public Const NoAnalItems As Integer = 35                ' Number of analysis items
'
' Define SA_Array and declare SCHED_ANAL
'
Public Type SA_Array                ' SA = Schedule Analysis
    Item As String                  ' Name of the analysis item
    SAT As Single                   ' Number of tasks for the entire schedule
    SOT As Single                   ' Number of open tasks
    PAT As Single                   ' Number of tasks for the entered period
    POT As Single                   ' Number of open tasks for the entered period
    WT As Integer                   ' Quality score weight
    Category As String              ' Category of the analysis item
    Description As String           ' Decription of the item for display on the help screen
    Risk As String                  ' Risk associated with the item for display on the help screen
    ExecuteCheckbox As CheckBox     ' Pointer to associated analysis item checkbox; TRUE if executed, FALSE if not
    RepairButton As CommandButton   ' Pointer to associated analysis item repair button
End Type
Public SCHED_ANAL(NoAnalItems) As SA_Array


Function qsM(stype)
'
' Title:    qsM
' Author:   11/21/2023 by Gary E. Didio
' Purpose:  Returns the milestone tasks quality score
'           stype is the type of task (all, open, period all, or period open)
'
On Error Resume Next

    Dim qs, qa, qw As Single
    qs = 0
    Dim t As SA_Array

    
    Select Case stype
        Case "SAT": qa = (SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).SAT * SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).SAT * SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).SAT * SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).WT)
                    If (SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).SAT <> 0) Then qa = qa / SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).SAT
        
        Case "SOT": qa = (SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).SOT * SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).SOT * SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).SOT * SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).WT)
                    If (SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).SOT <> 0) Then qa = qa / SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).SOT
        
        Case "PAT": qa = (SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).PAT * SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).PAT * SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).PAT * SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).WT)
                    If (SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).PAT <> 0) Then qa = qa / SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).PAT
        
        Case "POT": qa = (SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).POT * SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).POT * SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).WT) + (SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).POT * SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).WT)
                    If (SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).POT <> 0) Then qa = qa / SCHED_ANAL(pMTotl).POT
    End Select
    qw = SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).WT + SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).WT + SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).WT
    qs = (1 - qa / qw) * 100
    qsM = Format(qs, "#0.0")

End Function
```

I tried using the CallByName function, but do not believe it is appropriate for data structures.  At a loss on what else to try.

Comment: You can use a single function wrapping a Select Case which returns the appropriate field from an instance of one of your Type's  CallByName only works with objects (or you can make your Type into a Class with public fields)

Comment: It would seem that SAT, SOT, PAT and POT would be constant across the 35 analysis items. If so, pull those out of the custom type and have them be global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the number of the `Select Case stype...` statements, factor that out into its own function "TaskCount" which takes two arguments: 1) the index of the array, 2) the name of the group of tasks.

```
Public Const NoAnalItems As Integer = 35                ' Number of analysis items

Public Type SA_Array                ' SA = Schedule Analysis
    Item As String                  ' Name of the analysis item
    SAT As Long                     ' whole schedule, all task count
    SOT As Long                     ' whole schedule, open task count
    PAT As Long                     ' period, all task count
    POT As Long                     ' period, open task count
    WT As Integer                   ' Quality score weight
    Category As String              ' Category of the analysis item
    Description As String           ' Decription of the item for display on the help screen
    Risk As String                  ' Risk associated with the item for display on the help screen
    ExecuteCheckbox As CheckBox     ' Pointer to associated analysis item checkbox; TRUE if executed, FALSE if not
    RepairButton As CommandButton   ' Pointer to associated analysis item repair button
End Type
Public SCHED_ANAL(NoAnalItems) As SA_Array


Function TaskCount(idx As Integer, sType As String) As Long
    Select Case sType
        Case Is = "SAT": TaskCount = SCHED_ANAL(idx).SAT
        Case Is = "SOT": TaskCount = SCHED_ANAL(idx).SOT
        Case Is = "PAT": TaskCount = SCHED_ANAL(idx).PAT
        Case Is = "POT": TaskCount = SCHED_ANAL(idx).POT
    End Select
End Function

Function qsM(sType As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim NumTasks As Long
    NumTasks = TaskCount(pMDurn, sType)
    
    Dim qa As Single
    qa = (NumTasks * SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).WT) + (NumTasks * SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).WT) + (NumTasks * SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).WT)
    If NumTasks <> 0 Then
        qa = qa / NumTasks
    End If

    Dim qw As Single
    qw = SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).WT + SCHED_ANAL(pMFixd).WT + SCHED_ANAL(pMPred).WT
    
    Dim qs As Single
    qs = (1 - qa / qw) * 100
    
    qsM = Format(qs, "#0.0")

End Function
```

Note: When declared like this: `Dim qs, qa, qw As Single`, only qw is declared as Single which initialize as 0, the rest are variants which initialize as Empty. Declare each variable on its own line to avoid erroneous declarations as Variant.

PS This could also be done with a class module instead of the custom Type which would allow a construct such as `SCHED_ANAL(pMDurn).TaskCount(sType)`. However, the overhead required for that single construct would be too much. Keep an eye out, however, for other parts of the code that would work better with SCHED_ANAL as a class which could tip the scales.

Comment: Thank you, Rachel.  

There are two different arrays that have multiple instances of SAT, SOT, PAT, and POT which are different in each instance.  Task counts are computed and stored in the SCHED_ANAL array, of which there are 35 different counts.  As an example, a quality score is computed for all milestone tasks (SAT), all open milestone tasks (SOT), all milestone tasks within a specified time period (PAT), and all open milestone tasks within the period (POT).  In all there are 80 separate quality scores computed:  4 types (SAT, SOT, PAT, POT) x 20 individual scores.

Comment: Task counts include summary tasks with predecessors, summary tasks with successors, summary tasks with resources, milestone tasks with duration, milestone tasks with fixed dates, etc.  These task counts are then used to determine the various quality scores.

Comment: I was hoping to do something like the following, but I know it is not correct:

```vba

Function qsB(stype)

On Error Resume Next

    Dim qs, qa, qw As Single

    qs = 0
    
    qa = SCHED_ANAL(pNBase).stype* SCHED_ANAL(pNBase).WT
                    If (SCHED_ANAL(pNTotl).stype<> 0) Then qa = qa / SCHED_ANAL(pNTotl).stype
                            
    qw = SCHED_ANAL(pNBase).WT
    qs = (1 - qa / qw) * 100
    qsB = Format(qs, "#0.0")

End Function

Comment: @GaryE.Didio see updated answer--the TaskCount function now takes another argument--the index of the array.

Comment: Thank you, Rachel.  If I understand correctly, the TaskCount function simply retrieves the appropriate value based on the index and type (SAT, SOT, PAT, POT).  The second function is the quality score calculation.  Although there is a temporary result stored in NumTasks, I could just use the TaskCount function instead.  Is that correct?

Comment: Rachel, this worked great!  It will greatly simplify my code for calculating quality scores.  Thank you so much for your assistance!!!!!

Comment: Great! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)